# Slow DNS lookup on my site?

Tags: performance, dns

I'm testing the loading speeds of my [website](http://responsible-disclosure.com).

I've just done a test using [Pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) but it returns some strange (at least to me) results:

http://responsible-disclosure.com/img/pingdom-results.png

By the looks of it getting the DNS info takes the most time.

Is this normal? Is there something I can do to speed this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the network conditions (and the state of your LDNS resolver cache), its quite normal. You can try increasing the DNS TTL to around a day so that the record gets cached at LDNS resolvers. Right now its 1 hour for your FQDN.